# Receive assets on Handheld

Tags: wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I'm sending files from wear to handheld side. I'm sending 4 or 5 files (2 of them are bigger) but everytime the handheld side only receives ONE of the bigger ones...

**wear:**

```
public void sendFile(String filename){
    //BLE files
    fileToArray("BLEdata/" + filename + "_RightDevice.txt", "/BLEdata/");
    //send log file
    fileToArray(filename + "_LOG.txt", "/LOGdata/");
    //send GPS file
    fileToArray("GPSdata/" + filename + "_GPS.txt", "/GPSdata/");
    //send Report files
    fileToArray("Report/" + filename + "_Report.txt", "/REPORTdata/");
    //BLE files
    fileToArray("BLEdata/" + filename + "_LeftDevice.txt", "/BLEdata/");
}

public void fileToArray(String filename, String path)
{
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;

    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/TuneWear/"  + filename);

    System.out.println("PATH: " + file.getPath());

    if(file.exists()){
        byte[] bFile = new byte[(int) file.length()];

        try {
            //convert file into array of bytes
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            fileInputStream.read(bFile);
            fileInputStream.close();

            WearResultsActivity main = (WearResultsActivity) getActivity();
            long time = main.getInitTime();

            if(filename.contains("_RightDevice")){
                new SendToDataLayerThread(path + time, bFile, 2).start();
            }else if (filename.contains("_LeftDevice")){
                new SendToDataLayerThread(path + time, bFile, 1).start();
            } else
                new SendToDataLayerThread(path + time, bFile).start();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else System.out.println("Doesn't exist:\n" + file.getPath());
}

class SendToDataLayerThread extends Thread {
    String path;
    byte[] bFile;
    int footSide;

    // Constructor for sending data objects to the data layer
    SendToDataLayerThread(String p, byte[] bytes, int footside) {
        path = p;
        bFile = bytes;
        footSide = footside;
    }

    SendToDataLayerThread(String p, byte[] bytes) {
        path = p;
        bFile = bytes;
    }

    public void run() {
        WearResultsActivity main = (WearResultsActivity) getActivity();
        GoogleApiClient googleClient = main.getGoogleClient();
        Asset asset = Asset.createFromBytes(bFile);

        System.out.println(asset.toString());

        PutDataMapRequest dataMap = PutDataMapRequest.create(path);
        dataMap.getDataMap().putLong("timestamp", Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
        dataMap.getDataMap().putLong("/InitialTime", ((WearResultsActivity) getActivity()).getInitTime());
        dataMap.getDataMap().putAsset("asset", asset);
        if(footSide == 1) {
            dataMap.getDataMap().putInt("footside", footSide);
            System.out.println("DATAMAP COM LEFT " + footSide);
        }else if (footSide == 2) {
            dataMap.getDataMap().putInt("footside", footSide);
            System.out.println("DATAMAP COM RIGHT " + footSide);
        }
        PutDataRequest request = dataMap.asPutDataRequest();
        PendingResult<DataApi.DataItemResult> pendingResult = Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(googleClient, request);
        pendingResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DataApi.DataItemResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(DataApi.DataItemResult dataItemResult) {
                System.out.println("RESULT");
            }
        });
        //Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(googleClient, request);
    }
}
```

**Handheld:**

```
@Override
public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEvents) {
    System.out.println("COUNT " + dataEvents.getCount());
    for (DataEvent event : dataEvents) {
        DataItem item = event.getDataItem();
        if (event.getType() == DataEvent.TYPE_CHANGED) {
            // DataItem changed
            if (item.getUri().getPath().contains(LOGdata)) {
                final DataMapItem dataMapItem = DataMapItem.fromDataItem(item);
                Asset asset = dataMapItem.getDataMap().getAsset("asset");

                //TODO here
                Wearable.DataApi.getFdForAsset(googleClient, asset).setResultCallback(
                        new ResultCallback<DataApi.GetFdForAssetResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResult(DataApi.GetFdForAssetResult getFdForAssetResult) {
                                InputStream assetInputStream = getFdForAssetResult.getInputStream();

                                long initialTime = dataMapItem.getDataMap().getLong(KEY_INITIALTIME);
                                String fileName = new SimpleDateFormat("HH'h'mm'm'ss's'_dd-MM-yyyy").format(initialTime);
                                String dataPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/TuneWear/";

                                File myDir = new File(dataPath);
                                myDir.mkdirs();

                                File file = new File(myDir, "Run_" + fileName + "_LOG.txt");
                                System.out.println("FILE: " + file.getPath());
                                try {
                                    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                                    int nRead;
                                    byte[] data = new byte[16384];
                                    while ((nRead = assetInputStream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
                                        fOut.write(data, 0, nRead);
                                    }

                                    fOut.flush();
                                    fOut.close();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    System.out.println("ERROR File write failed: " + e.toString());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                );


            } else if (item.getUri().getPath().contains(GPSdata)) {
                final DataMapItem dataMapItem = DataMapItem.fromDataItem(item);
                Asset asset = dataMapItem.getDataMap().getAsset("asset");

                //TODO here
                Wearable.DataApi.getFdForAsset(googleClient, asset).setResultCallback(
                        new ResultCallback<DataApi.GetFdForAssetResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResult(DataApi.GetFdForAssetResult getFdForAssetResult) {
                                InputStream assetInputStream = getFdForAssetResult.getInputStream();

                                long initialTime = dataMapItem.getDataMap().getLong(KEY_INITIALTIME);
                                String fileName = new SimpleDateFormat("HH'h'mm'm'ss's'_dd-MM-yyyy").format(initialTime);
                                String dataPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/TuneWear/GPSdata/";

                                File myDir = new File(dataPath);
                                myDir.mkdirs();

                                File file = new File(myDir, "Run_" + fileName + "_GPS.txt");
                                System.out.println("FILE: " + file.getPath());
                                try {
                                    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                                    int nRead;
                                    byte[] data = new byte[16384];
                                    while ((nRead = assetInputStream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
                                        fOut.write(data, 0, nRead);
                                    }

                                    fOut.flush();
                                    fOut.close();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    System.out.println("ERROR File write failed: " + e.toString());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                );


            } else if (item.getUri().getPath().contains(REPORTdata)) {
                final DataMapItem dataMapItem = DataMapItem.fromDataItem(item);
                Asset asset = dataMapItem.getDataMap().getAsset("asset");


                //TODO here
                Wearable.DataApi.getFdForAsset(googleClient, asset).setResultCallback(
                        new ResultCallback<DataApi.GetFdForAssetResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResult(DataApi.GetFdForAssetResult getFdForAssetResult) {
                                InputStream assetInputStream = getFdForAssetResult.getInputStream();

                                long initialTime = dataMapItem.getDataMap().getLong(KEY_INITIALTIME);
                                String fileName = new SimpleDateFormat("HH'h'mm'm'ss's'_dd-MM-yyyy").format(initialTime);
                                String dataPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/TuneWear/Report/";

                                File myDir = new File(dataPath);
                                myDir.mkdirs();

                                File file = new File(myDir, "Run_" + fileName + "_Report.txt");
                                System.out.println("FILE: " + file.getPath());
                                try {
                                    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                                    int nRead;
                                    byte[] data = new byte[16384];
                                    while ((nRead = assetInputStream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
                                        fOut.write(data, 0, nRead);
                                    }

                                    fOut.flush();
                                    fOut.close();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    System.out.println("ERROR File write failed: " + e.toString());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                );
            } else if (item.getUri().getPath().contains(BLEdata)) {
                final DataMapItem dataMapItem = DataMapItem.fromDataItem(item);
                Asset asset = dataMapItem.getDataMap().getAsset("asset");                  

                //TODO here
                Wearable.DataApi.getFdForAsset(googleClient, asset).setResultCallback(
                        new ResultCallback<DataApi.GetFdForAssetResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResult(DataApi.GetFdForAssetResult getFdForAssetResult) {
                                InputStream assetInputStream = getFdForAssetResult.getInputStream();

                                long initialTime = dataMapItem.getDataMap().getLong(KEY_INITIALTIME);
                                String fileName = new SimpleDateFormat("HH'h'mm'm'ss's'_dd-MM-yyyy").format(initialTime);
                                String dataPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/TuneWear/BLEdata/";

                                File myDir = new File(dataPath);
                                myDir.mkdirs();

                                File file = null;
                                System.out.println("FOOT SIIIIIIDE: " + dataMapItem.getDataMap().getInt("footside"));
                                if(dataMapItem.getDataMap().getInt("footside") == 1){
                                    file = new File(myDir, "Run_" + fileName + "_LeftDevice.txt");
                                    System.out.println("FILE: " + file.getPath());
                                } else if(dataMapItem.getDataMap().getInt("footside") == 2){
                                    file = new File(myDir, "Run_" + fileName + "_RightDevice.txt");
                                    System.out.println("FILE: " + file.getPath());
                                }

                                try {
                                    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                                    int nRead;
                                    byte[] data = new byte[16384];
                                    while ((nRead = assetInputStream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
                                        fOut.write(data, 0, nRead);
                                    }

                                    fOut.flush();
                                    fOut.close();
                                }
                                catch (IOException e) {
                                    System.out.println("ERROR File write failed: " + e.toString());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                );
            }
        } else if (event.getType() == DataEvent.TYPE_DELETED) {
            // DataItem deleted
            System.out.println("DataItem deleted: " + event.getDataItem().getUri());
        }
        //Wearable.DataApi.deleteDataItems(googleClient, event.getDataItem().getUri(), DataApi.FILTER_PREFIX);
    }
}
```

I only receive the GPS, Report and LOG data every time. The other 2 files I only receive ONE... Im sending them exactly the same way, but I'm receiving only one of them.
Does anyone detects the error on my code???

**EDIT**
I just discovered that if the smartwatch is connected to the handheld at the time that the files are sent, they are all received. If they are not connected, one of the files (RightDevice.txt or LeftDevice.txt) are not received when they connect...

Comment: Is the data you are sending changing each time? The DataApi only sends data if there is a change in the data.

Comment: I'm sending different files so they are always different. Plus, the initialTime on the intent is always different from other iterations. So I send 5 files with the same initialTime (but diferent asset), in the iteration after, the initialTime will be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it!

It was the most basic error of all.... I was sending the same path for the two files (RightDevice and LeftDevice) so only one of the objects was updated on the googleapiclient.